# Adobe AIR and unexpected error when entering text

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a finite application in AIR (as3) for mobile devices (Android) and appeared one problem - when entering text into a text field (its no flash component - this is editable textfield) or a textarea, when I push the space bar, or try to set the pointer somewhere on the entered text, I get an error and text is copied.
Alternative error: text-pointer sets are always at the beginning and not the end of the entered text.
This makes it virtually impossible to enter longer phrases or even two words.

I tested on a Samsung Galaxy S +. I do not have any other way of checking.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have any code in this application?

Comment: In the cage, which is texfield is only this code:

import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;

var memp1: TextField;
var memp2: TextField;

Nothing more - no import or other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices, try using Native Text: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html

Comment: OK - if it is too lame question, I apologize.
Can somebody give me a ride even tips on how to apply the spreading links to applications written in adobe professional cc?
I'm at the stage of learning, moving from as2 to as3 and even though I'm doing well, it's still a lot I need to learn.

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: look into that: http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233